# How do I show the numeric character sequence of a string?

Tags: text-processing, utilities, string

Is there a command either standalone or in vi or similar (can be gui) that will show me the numeric sequence of a string?

Input: 
The cat hopped in a box.

Output:

```
T h e   c a t   h o  p  p  e  d     i  n     a     b  o  x  .
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Comment: Not the exact output that you want but you can run strings into `od -c` to show numbered output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a hybrid perl/fold approach:

```
$ echo "The cat hopped in a box." | fold -w 1 | 
     perl -lne 'push @k, "$_ "; push @l,sprintf "%-2s",$.; END{print "@k\n@l"}'
T  h  e     c  a  t     h  o  p  p  e  d     i  n     a     b  o  x  . 
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

#### Explanation

- `fold -w 1`: this will fold the input at a width of one character, resulting in each input character printed on a separate line.
- `perl -lne` : the `-l` removes trailing newlines from the input and adds a newline to each `print` call; the `n` reads input line by line and the `e` provides the script to run on it.
- `push @k, " $_";` : Add a space to the the current line (`$_`) and save it in in the array `@k`.
- `push @l,sprintf "%-2s",$.;` : `sprintf` will return a formatted string, here we are giving it the current line number (`$.`) and telling it to print it with spaces added as needed to make its length 2. The string is then added to the `@l` array.
- `END{print "@k\n@l"}'` : once the whole file has been read, print the two arrays.

---

If you just need to number the characters and don't mind multi-line output, a simpler approach is (using a shorter string for brevity):

```
$ echo "foo bar" | fold -w1 | cat -n
 1  f
 2  o
 3  o
 4   
 5  b
 6  a
 7  r
```

Comment: I think the second approach is much better - once the input string goes over about 30 characters and starts to wrap, the one-per-line output ensures you still have the numbers and the letters aligned. The perl example would need some more work to interlace properly.

Answer (score 7):

It's very simple to use the shell and basic tools:

```
$ echo "The cat hopped in a box." |
    (read a ; echo $a | sed 's/./&  /g' ; seq -ws" " 01 ${#a})
 T  h  e     c  a  t     h  o  p  p  e  d     i  n     a     b  o  x  .  
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

#### Explanation

The string is read into the `$a` variable. The `(  )` will run the commands inside them in a [subshell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), needed to make the `$a` variable accessible. It is then passed to `sed` which replaces each character with itself followed by two spaces. Finally, the `seq` command prints a `0`-padded list of numbers from `01` to the length of the `$a` string.

Comment: You don't need the subshell; the command work if you replace `( )` with `{ ;}`.

Answer (score 6):

`zsh`:

```
$ text='The cat hopped in a box.'
$ chars=(${(s::)text})
$ print -aC$#chars $chars {1..$#chars}
T   h   e       c   a   t       h   o   p   p   e   d       i   n       a       b   o   x   .
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `perl`:

```
$ echo The cat hopped in a box. | perl -nle '
    printf "%-3s", $_ for split //;
    printf "\n";
    printf "%-3s", $_ for 1..length'
T  h  e     c  a  t     h  o  p  p  e  d     i  n     a     b  o  x  .  
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```